# Limit dependency on reactiveValues in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the example below how can I prevent the `renderUI()` from being trigger every time a value from `rv` is changed? Ideally, I would only want `renderUI()` to be triggered when a new index is added to `rv`, iei. by pressing the `generate_index` button. How can I achieve this? I'm looking for the least cumbersum solution. Also, I do need to used a nested list (`rv$slot`).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('generate_index', 'Generate new index'),
  actionButton('change_index', 'Change index value'),
  uiOutput('ui_select'),
  verbatimTextOutput('verbatim')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$generate_index, {
    new_index <- paste(sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
    rv$slot[[new_index]] <- rnorm(1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$change_index, {
    req(rv$slot)
    rv$slot[[1]] <- rnorm(1)
  })
  
  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    showNotification('Choices updated')
    choices <- names(rv$slot)
    selectInput('select_index', 'Select index', choices = choices)
  })
  
  output$verbatim <- renderPrint({
    str(reactiveValuesToList(rv))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. However, I wonder if there's a way to avoid relying on an extra `observeEvent()` event.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('generate_index', 'Generate new index'),
  actionButton('change_index', 'Change index value'),
  uiOutput('ui_select'),
  verbatimTextOutput('verbatim')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$generate_index, {
    new_index <- paste(sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
    rv$slot[[new_index]] <- rnorm(1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$change_index, {
    req(rv$slot)
    rv$slot[[1]] <- rnorm(1)
  })
  
  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    showNotification('Choices updated')
    selectInput('select_index', 'Select index', choices = rv$names)
  })
  
  output$verbatim <- renderPrint({
    str(reactiveValuesToList(rv))
  })
  
  observeEvent(rv$slot, {
    names_rv <- names(rv$slot)
    if (is.null(rv$names) ||
        length(rv$names) != length(names_rv) ||
        any(names_rv != rv$names)) {
      rv$names <- names_rv
    } 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think isolate() should fix your issue

```
output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    showNotification('Choices updated')
    isolate({
      choices <- names(rv$slot)
    })
    selectInput('select_index', 'Select index', choices = choices)
  })
```

Comment: It does not work. With this isolate you break any dependency on the `rv$slot` names, so the input won't have any choices to select from.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use another reactive value, `render` in the app below, which will be updated each time a new value is added to `rv$slot`, and to bind the `renderUI` to this reactive value:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  render <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$generate_index, {
    new_index <- paste(sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
    rv$slot[[new_index]] <- rnorm(1)
    render(render() + 1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$change_index, {
    req(rv$slot)
    rv$slot[[1]] <- rnorm(1)
  })
  
  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    showNotification('Choices updated')
    choices <- names(rv$slot)
    selectInput('select_index', 'Select index', choices = choices)
  }) |> bindEvent(render(), ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  output$verbatim <- renderPrint({
    str(reactiveValuesToList(rv))
  })
}
```

I firstly tried to bind the button click:

```r
  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    showNotification('Choices updated')
    choices <- names(rv$slot)
    selectInput('select_index', 'Select index', choices = choices)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$generate_index)
```

but that does not work as expected because the `rv$slot` is updated after the button click.